# Is there a layer from a color model (RGB, CMYK, etc), that is better for edge detection?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to extract certain features from an image, is there a layer of any color model that is better for say edge detection?? Like, in RGB the green layer has more information for image processing.

Comment: It will depend on the objects you're trying to detect.  Simplest case, convert RGB to Greyscale.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the kinda of edges that people see - grayscale is probably best.  That would be the L value in HSL or Lab/Lch/Luv color space.